# Merge array of javascript objects by property key

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, javascript-objects

First of all: I already found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26476287/merge-an-array-of-javascript-objects-based-on-a-key-property-multilevel), which basically is exactly what I want, but I tried my best to apply it to my needs - I couldn't.

So, I have the following javascript function:

```js
function loadRelationData(object) {
    var result = [];
    var parents = []
    parents = getParentObjectsByObjectID(object['ObjectID']);

    var tmpFirstObjects = [];
    var tmpOtherObjects = [];
    $.each(parents, function (_, parent) {
        var keyName = 'Übergeordnete ' + parent['ObjectType'];
        var pushObject = {};
        if (parent['ObjectType'] == object['ObjectType']) {
            pushObject['Fieldname'] = keyName;
            pushObject['Value'] = parent['Name'];
            tmpFirstObjects.push(pushObject);
        } else {
            pushObject['Fieldname'] = keyName;
            pushObject['Value'] = parent['Name'];
            tmpOtherObjects.push(pushObject);
        }
    });
    result = result.concat(tmpFirstObjects).concat(tmpOtherObjects);

    return result;
}
```

The parents array looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQ6nb.png)

And my function creates this [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/od9DY.png)

This might be a bit complicated, but I need to split it up like this, because I need the order.

What I want is an array with both "TEC_MapLocations" joined together like this:

```
[
 {Fieldname: 'Übergeordnete TEC_Equipment', Value: 'E0192'}, 
 {Fieldname: 'Übergeordnete TEC_MapLocation', Value: ['M100', 'M200']}, 
 {Fieldname: 'Übergeordnete TEC_FunctionalLocation', Value: 'FL456'}
]
```

Any ideas on how to alter my code to achieve the desired result right away or how to merge the results array?

**edit:** I used [Joseph's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32481768/5307891) and used the following (quick and dirty) sort function to get back my desired sorting:

```
output.sort(function (a, b) {
    if (a.ObjectType == object.ObjectType) {
        return -1
    } else {
        return 1
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you'd want to do first is build a hash with `Fieldname` as key, and an array as value. Then you'd want to use `reduce` to add the values into the hash and array. Then you can transform it into an array using `Object.keys` and `map`.

```js
var input = [
  {Name: 'M100', ObjectID: 1, ObjectType: 'TEC_MapLocation'},
  {Name: 'M200', ObjectID: 2, ObjectType: 'TEC_MapLocation'},
  {Name: 'FL456', ObjectID: 4, ObjectType: 'TEC_FunctionalLocation'},
  {Name: 'E0192', ObjectID: 5, ObjectType: 'TEC_Equipment'}
];

var hash = input.reduce(function(carry, item){
  
  // Create the name
  var name = 'Übergeordnete ' + item.ObjectType;

  // If array with name doesn't exist, create it
  if(!carry[name]) carry[name] = [];

  // If item isn't in the array, add it.
  if(!~carry[name].indexOf(item.Name)) carry[name].push(item.Name);

  return carry;
}, {});

// Convert the hash into an array
var output = Object.keys(hash).map(function(key, index, array){
  return { Fieldname: key, Value: hash[key] }
});

document.write(JSON.stringify(output));
```

Comment: Thank you, it works very well! But there is one thing missing: my function keeps the "TEC_Equipment" object in front, because that's where I need it. Your solution just sorts the results by ID.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function joinObjects( array ) {

    // Start with empty array
    var ret = new Array();

    // Iterate array
    for ( var i = 0; i < array.length; i++ ) {

        // Search by fieldname
        var match = false;
        var j;
        for ( j = 0; j < ret.length; j++ ) {
            if ( array[i].Fieldname == ret[j].Fieldname ) { match = true; break; }
        }

        // If not exists
        if ( !match ) {

            // Intert object
            ret.push({
                Fieldname: array[i].Fieldname,
                Value: new Array()
            });

        }

        // Insert value
        ret[j].Value.push( array[i].Value );

    }

    // Return new array
    return ret;

}
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/6entfv4x/**

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but your solution creates a different array structure for the result.