# Combine json arrays by key, javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, algorithm

I need to combine two json arrays, delivered by two rest services. The entries with the same "id" belong together.

```
json1 = [{id:1,name:'aaa'},
     {id:5,name:'ccc'},
     {id:3,name:'bbb'}
   ];

 json2 = [{id:3,parameter1:'x', parameter2:'y', parameter3:'z'},
     {id:1,parameter1:'u', parameter2:'v', parameter3:'w'},
     {id:5,parameter1:'q', parameter2:'w', parameter3:'e'}
    ];
```

I need a combined/copied/cloned json array in javascript in the following way (my model in angular2):

```
json3 = [{id:3,name:'bbb',parameter1:'x', parameter2:'y',   parameter3:'z'},
     {id:1,name:'aaa', parameter1:'u', parameter2:'v', parameter3:'w'},
     {id:5,name:'ccc', parameter1:'q', parameter2:'w', parameter3:'e'}
    ];
```

Is there a way to combine them? The parameter names are not defined exactly and it needs to work with variable parameter vectors.

I tried it with mixed for each loops. Seems to me very ugly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge two arrays in Javascript and de-duplicate items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584370/how-to-merge-two-arrays-in-javascript-and-de-duplicate-items)

Comment: @Doctus, that question does not deal with nested properties.

Comment: @Doctus, i think my question is different. I do not just want to combine and eliminate double entries, i want to merge the key-value pairs of both json arrays, based on a unique key in the json objects.

Comment: > I tried it with mixed for each loops. Seems to me very ugly. - try `forEach` with arrow functions - it would look a bit better.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge array of javascript objects by property key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32481446/merge-array-of-javascript-objects-by-property-key)

Comment: This question is ***not*** a duplicate of [How to merge two arrays in JavaScript and de-duplicate items](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35903850). The two questions are essentially different.

Comment: If you are interested in this question, chances are that you will also want to look at
[Merge two array of objects based on a key](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46849286).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you wanted to write it so that you could take in any number of arrays, not
just 2, you could utilize [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments), and do something like this:

```js
var json1 = [{id:1,name:'aaa'},{id:5,name:'ccc'},{id:3,name:'bbb'}];

var json2 = [{id:3,parameter1:'x', parameter2:'y', parameter3:'z'},
             {id:1,parameter1:'u', parameter2:'v', parameter3:'w'},
             {id:5,parameter1:'q', parameter2:'w', parameter3:'e'}];

function joinObjects() {
  var idMap = {};
  // Iterate over arguments
  for(var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    // Iterate over individual argument arrays (aka json1, json2)
    for(var j = 0; j < arguments[i].length; j++) {
      var currentID = arguments[i][j]['id'];
      if(!idMap[currentID]) {
        idMap[currentID] = {};
      }
      // Iterate over properties of objects in arrays (aka id, name, etc.)
      for(key in arguments[i][j]) {
        idMap[currentID][key] = arguments[i][j][key];
      }
    }
  }
  
  // push properties of idMap into an array
  var newArray = [];
  for(property in idMap) {
    newArray.push(idMap[property]);
  }
  return newArray;
}

var json3 = joinObjects(json1, json2);

console.log(JSON.stringify(json3));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

[Here is a working codepen.](http://codepen.io/peteTalksWeb/pen/QNNzZE?editors=1111)

Answer (score 59):

Two one-liners:

with lodash:

```
res = _(json1).concat(json2).groupBy('id').map(_.spread(_.assign)).value();
```

in ES2015:

```
res = json2.map(x => Object.assign(x, json1.find(y => y.id == x.id)));
```

Comment: I wrote a set of functions for this last night in 8 lines and about 2 hrs. I used only map and filter. How the hell did I forget that there are other Array methods?! Upvote for Object.assign though didn't think of that either. Used a spread operator. Yours is sorter and easier to read.

Comment: Is there an equivalent in underscore?

Comment: Is there a way to merge the new items from json2 also, not only that exists on both?

Comment: @Joel I just found this sample of outerJoin using Ramda: https://github.com/ramda/ramda/wiki/Cookbook#sql-style-joins

`const joinOuter = R.curry((f1, f2, t1, t2) => {
        let o1 = R.indexBy(f1, t1);
  let o2 = R.indexBy(f2, t2);
  return R.values(R.mergeWith(R.merge, o1, o2));
});
// usage: joinOuter(R.prop('id'), R.prop('buyer'), people, transactions)
// result:
// [{ id: 1, name: 'me', buyer: 1, seller: 10 },
//  { buyer: 2, seller: 5 },
//  { id: 3, name: 'you' }]
`

Comment: I have found that the **Lodash** solution is a _full outer join_, meaning each item from both `json1` and `json2` are merged into the result - irrespective of whether the item is also in the other array. The **Object.assign** solution is a _left outer join_, meaning _all_ items from `json1` go into the result, but items in `json2` are joined into the result _only_ if they also exist in `json1`. For a solution giving a _true inner join_, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67299551).

Comment: It deserves to be noted that for both the Lodash and the Object.assign solutions, the left array is _updated_ to hold the result.
If you want to avoid this, see
[Stack snippets of the two one-liners](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66659834).

Answer (score 11):

ES2015 georg's answer works great;

```
    json1 = [
    {id:1, test: 0},
    {id:2, test: 0},
    {id:3, test: 0},
    {id:4, test: 0},
    {id:5, test: 0}
];

json2 = [
    {id:1, test: 1},
    {id:3, test: 1},
    {id:5, test: 1}
];

json1.map(x => Object.assign(x, json2.find(y => y.id == x.id)));
```

result:

```
{id:1, test: 1},
{id:2, test: 0},
{id:3, test: 1},
{id:4, test: 0},
{id:5, test: 1}
```

Comment: This doesn't achieve what was asked in the Question.

Answer (score 5):

```js
let json1 = [
  { id: 1, name: 'aaa' },
  { id: 5, name: 'ccc' },
  { id: 3, name: 'bbb' }
];

let json2 = [
  { id: 3, parameter1: 'x', parameter2: 'y', parameter3: 'z' },
  { id: 1, parameter1: 'u', parameter2: 'v', parameter3: 'w' },
  { id: 5, parameter1: 'q', parameter2: 'w', parameter3: 'e' }
];

let result = json1.map(obj => {
  let data = json2.find(item => item.id === obj.id);
  return {...obj, ...data}
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: A nicer looking answer than many here.  You might want to [make this a stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/35899).

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript:

```js
let json1 = [
  { id: 1, name: 'aaa' },
  { id: 5, name: 'ccc' },
  { id: 3, name: 'bbb' }
];

let json2 = [
  { id: 3, parameter1: 'x', parameter2: 'y', parameter3: 'z' },
  { id: 1, parameter1: 'u', parameter2: 'v', parameter3: 'w' },
  { id: 5, parameter1: 'q', parameter2: 'w', parameter3: 'e' }
];

let json3 = [];

json1.forEach((j1) => {
  json2.forEach((j2) => {
    if (j1.id === j2.id) {
      json3.push({ ...j1, ...j2 });
    }
  });
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(json3));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: This is a fine answer, demonstrating a _true inner join_ of the two arrays. In fact, I have not seen _any_ other answer to this question that does exactly that. Nor among the answers to the questions [Merge two array of objects based on a key](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46849286) or [How can I perform an inner join with two object arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42429023). (The last question _verbally_ asks for an _inner join_, but by the description and the output example it is actually a question asking for a _full outer join_.)

Answer (score 1):

Use nested loops to find the corresponding elements and merge them.

```
for (var i = 0; i < json1.length; i++) {
    var id = json1[i].id;
    for (var j = 0; j < json2.length; j++) {
        if (json2[j].id == id) {
            for (var key in json2[j]) {
                json1[i][key] = json2[j][key];
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

At the end, `json1` will contain the combined elements.

The above code assumes that every element of `json2` matches something in `json1`. If there can be extra elements in `json2`, you'll need an additional loop afterward to copy those over to `json1`.

Comment: on large data set it would be more effective to convert smaller array into sparse array (by using id as index) and cut nested loop.

Comment: Yeah, that's how I usually do it, I decided to write the quick-and-dirty version this time.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way where you first build an index keyed by *id* (sparse array) to detect and combine objects with matching *id* values, which then finally are concatenated back into a normal array:

```
json3 = json1.concat(json2).reduce(function(index, obj) {
    if (!index[obj.id]) {
        index[obj.id] = obj;
    } else {
        for (prop in obj) {
            index[obj.id][prop] = obj[prop];
        }
    }
    return index;
}, []).filter(function(res, obj) {
    return obj;
});
```

```js
json1 = [
    {id:1,name:'aaa'},
    {id:5,name:'ccc'},
    {id:3,name:'bbb'}
];

json2 = [
    {id:3,parameter1:'x', parameter2:'y', parameter3:'z'},
    {id:1,parameter1:'u', parameter2:'v', parameter3:'w'},
    {id:5,parameter1:'q', parameter2:'w', parameter3:'e'}
];

json3 = json1.concat(json2).reduce(function(index, obj) {
    if (!index[obj.id]) {
        index[obj.id] = obj;
    } else {
        for (prop in obj) {
            index[obj.id][prop] = obj[prop];
        }
    }
    return index;
}, []).filter(function(res, obj) {
    return obj;
});

document.write('<pre>', JSON.stringify(json3, null, 4), '</pre>');
```

If your browser supports [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```
json3 = json1.concat(json2).reduce(function(index, obj) {
    index[obj.id] = Object.assign({}, obj, index[obj.id]);
    return index;
}, []).filter(function(res, obj) {
    return obj;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **forEach** and **filter** we can resolve the requirement.

```js
vehicleArray1 = [{id:1, name: "a"},{id:2, name: "b"},{id:3, name:"c"}];
vehicleArray2 = [{id:1, type: "two wheeler"},{id:2, type: "four wheeler"},{id:3, type:"six wheeler"}];
var outArr = [];
vehicleArray1.forEach(function(value) {
    var existing = vehicleArray2.filter(function(v, i) {
        return (v.id == value.id);
    });
    if (existing.length) {
        value.type = existing[0].type;
        outArr.push(value)
    } else {
        value.type = '';
        outArr.push(value);
    }
});
console.log(outArr)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it for you. I hope the code makes sense on its own. This example will always take the `json1` value over the `json2` value if both exist. If you want to change that then you need to switch the object references (`src[i]` and `obj[j]`) in the innermost loop.

```js
// Will take src, and merge in the contents of obj.
// Expects an array of objects for both.
// Will keep src values in favour of obj values.
function extend(src, obj) {
  
  // Loop the src, in this case json1
  for (var i = 0; i < src.length; i++) {
    
    // For every loop of json1, also loop json2
    for (var j = 0; j < obj.length; j++) {
      
      // If we have matching IDs operate on this pair
      if (src[i].id == obj[j].id) {
          
        // For every key in the object being merged in,
        // if the key exists in src, ignore new value.
        // if the doesn't exist in src, take the new value.
        for (var key in obj[j]) {
          src[i][key] = src[i].hasOwnProperty(key) ? src[i][key] : obj[j][key];
        }
        
        // We found our matching pair, so break out of the json2 loop
        break;
        
      }
      
    }
    
  }
  
  return src;
}

// -------------------------------------------

var json1 = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'aaa'
},{
  id: 5,
  name: 'ccc'
},{
  id: 3,
  name: 'bbb'
}];

var json2 = [{
  id: 3,
  parameter1: 'x', 
  parameter2: 'y', 
  parameter3: 'z'
},{
  id: 1,
  parameter1: 'u', 
  parameter2: 'v', 
  parameter3: 'w'
},{
  id: 5,
  parameter1: 'q', 
  parameter2: 'w', 
  parameter3: 'e'
}];

var json3 = extend(json1, json2);

// ---------------------------------------------

var pre = document.getElementById('out');
pre.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(json3);
```

```html
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generic solution using [object-lib](https://github.com/blackflux/object-lib).

The advantage is that you get full control over how objects are merged and this supports nested and multiple nested groupBys.

```js
// const objectLib = require('object-lib');

const { Merge } = objectLib;

const json1 = [{ id: 1, name: 'aaa' }, { id: 5, name: 'ccc' }, { id: 3, name: 'bbb' }];
const json2 = [{ id: 3, parameter1: 'x', parameter2: 'y', parameter3: 'z' }, { id: 1, parameter1: 'u', parameter2: 'v', parameter3: 'w' }, { id: 5, parameter1: 'q', parameter2: 'w', parameter3: 'e' }];

const groupById = Merge({ '[*]': 'id' });
console.log(groupById(json1, json2));
// => [ { id: 1, name: 'aaa', parameter1: 'u', parameter2: 'v', parameter3: 'w' }, { id: 5, name: 'ccc', parameter1: 'q', parameter2: 'w', parameter3: 'e' }, { id: 3, name: 'bbb', parameter1: 'x', parameter2: 'y', parameter3: 'z' } ]

const o1 = [{ id: 1, children: [{ type: 'A' }, { type: 'C' }] }, { id: 5 }];
const o2 = [{ id: 1, children: [{ type: 'A' }, { type: 'B' }] }, { id: 3 }];

console.log(groupById(o1, o2));
// => [ { id: 1, children: [ { type: 'A' }, { type: 'C' }, { type: 'A' }, { type: 'B' } ] }, { id: 5 }, { id: 3 } ]

const groupByCustom = Merge({
  '[*]': 'id',
  '[*].children[*]': 'type'
});
console.log(groupByCustom(o1, o2));
// => [ { id: 1, children: [ { type: 'A' }, { type: 'C' }, { type: 'B' } ] }, { id: 5 }, { id: 3 } ]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-lib@2.0.0"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-lib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-lib)

Answer (score 0):

#### Stack snippets of [the two one-liners](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35904655)

**Lodash**

```js
const json1 = [{ id: 1, name: 'aaa' }, { id: 3, name: 'bbb' },
  { id: 5, name: 'ccc' }];
const json2 = [{ id: 3, parameters: 'xyz' },
  { id: 5, parameters: 'qwe' }, { id: 1, parameters: 'uvw' }];
console.log('json1 BEFORE:\n' + JSON.stringify(json1));

const result_Lodash =
  _(json1).concat(json2).groupBy('id').map(_.spread(_.assign)).value();
console.log('Result, Lodash:\n' + JSON.stringify(result_Lodash));
console.log('json1 AFTER:\n' + JSON.stringify(json1));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src=
"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.js"></script>
```

---

**Object.assign**

```js
const json1 = [{ id: 1, name: 'aaa' }, { id: 3, name: 'bbb' },
  { id: 5, name: 'ccc' }];
const json2 = [{ id: 3, parameters: 'xyz' },
  { id: 5, parameters: 'qwe' }, { id: 1, parameters: 'uvw' }];
console.log('json2 BEFORE:\n' + JSON.stringify(json2));

const result_Object_assign =
  json2.map(x => Object.assign(x, json1.find(y => y.id === x.id)));
console.log('Object.assign:\n' + JSON.stringify(result_Object_assign));
console.log('json2 AFTER:\n' + JSON.stringify(json2));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src=
"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.js"></script>
```

It is worth pointing out that for both solutions, the contents of the *first*
/ *left* array are changed.
Run the snippets to see it.
For example, `Object.assign(x, json1.find(y => y.id === x.id))` *copies* the
compound data to the object `x` in `json2`, and the objects in `json2` are
thus updated via `.map()`.
The identifier `result_Object_assign` is actually nothing but another pointer
that points to the very same array as `json2` points to - no new object is
created!

---

**Object.assign without changing the input arrays**
If you don't want to change any of the input arrays, simply create a new
array, as shown below:

```js
const json1 = [{ id: 1, name: 'aaa' }, { id: 3, name: 'bbb' },
  { id: 5, name: 'ccc' }];
const json2 = [{ id: 3, parameters: 'xyz' },
  { id: 5, parameters: 'qwe' }, { id: 1, parameters: 'uvw' }];
console.log('json2 BEFORE:\n' + JSON.stringify(json2));

const result_Object_assign =
  json2.map(x => Object.assign({}, x, json1.find(y => y.id === x.id)));
console.log('Object.assign:\n' + JSON.stringify(result_Object_assign));
console.log('json2 AFTER:\n' + JSON.stringify(json2));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src=
"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Stack snippets of [the concat-reduce answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35904329)

**Result 1: using reduce and *matching id's*.**
First concatenate the two arrays into a single array, then detect and combine
objects with matching id's. Finally filter out all `null` values.

**Result 2: using reduce and *Object.assign*.**

```js
const json1 = [{id:1,name:'aaa'},{id:3,name:'bbb'},{id:5,name:'ccc'}];
const json2 =
  [{id:3,parameters:'xyz'},{id:5,parameters:'qwe'},{id:1,parameters:'uvw'}];
const json7 = json1.concat(json2);
console.log(' json7:\n'+JSON.stringify(json7));

const Result_1 =
  json7.reduce((accumulator, obj) => {
    if (!accumulator[obj.id]) {
      accumulator[obj.id] = obj;
    } else {
      for (proprty in obj) { accumulator[obj.id][proprty] = obj[proprty];}
    }
    return accumulator;
  }, []).filter(x => x);
console.log('\n Result_1:\n' + JSON.stringify(Result_1));

const Result_2 =
  json1.concat(json2).reduce((accumulator, obj) => {
    accumulator[obj.id] = Object.assign({}, accumulator[obj.id], obj);
    return accumulator;
  }, []).filter(x => x);
console.log('\n Result_2:\n' + JSON.stringify(Result_2));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

#### References:

- [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#syntax)
- [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)