# JS: How can I merge/join arrays of objects by a certain key/property?

Tags: javascript, join, merge

What is the best way to join data in JavaScript? Are there libraries like e.g. `Pandas` in `Python` or is iteration the way to go? I have two arrays with different objects inside. The list `orders` contains information about orders in general and the list `ordersPayed` contains the information whether an order was already payed + the amount etc.

```js
const orders = [
{
    orderId: 1,
    orderDate: '2018-01-01',
    orderAmount: 100
},
{
    orderId: 2,
    orderDate: '2018-02-01',
    orderAmount: 100
},
{
    orderId: 3,
    orderDate: '2018-03-01',
    orderAmount: 100
},
{
    orderId: 4,
    orderDate: '2018-03-01',
    orderAmount: 100
}];
    
const ordersPayed = [
{
    orderId: 1,
    payedAmount: 90,
    debitorName: 'abc'
},
{
    orderId: 3,
    payedAmount: 80,
    debitorName: 'abc'
},
{
    orderId: 6,
    payedAmount: 90,
    debitorName: 'abc'
}];

let newOrderList = [];
    
for (i = 0; i < orders.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < ordersPayed.length; j++) {
        if (orders[i].orderId == ordersPayed[j].orderId) {
            newOrderList.push(orders[i].orderId);
            newOrderList.push(orders[i].orderDate);
            newOrderList.push(orders[i].orderAmount);
            newOrderList.push(ordersPayed[j].payedAmount);
            newOrderList.push(ordersPayed[j].debitorName);
        }
        else if (j == (ordersPayed.length-1)) {
            newOrderList.push(orders[i].orderId);
            newOrderList.push(orders[i].orderDate);
            newOrderList.push(orders[i].orderAmount);
            newOrderList.push('not_payed_yet');
            newOrderList.push('not_known_yet');
        }
    }
}
    
console.log(newOrderList);
```

The matching is done by the key `orderId`. At the end I want to have a new list with all orders + the corresponding info whether they were already payed or not.

The code above is my approach to go, but I don't know if this is good for performance reasons and whether there are more pitfalls. So I thought of a matching library or something similar.

Unfortunately this doesn't work 100% correctly. The result should look something like this:

```
[{
    orderId: 1,
    orderDate: '2018-01-01',
    orderAmount: 100,
    payedAmount: 90
},
{
    orderId: 2,
    orderDate: '2018-02-01',
    orderAmount: 100,
    payedAmount: 'not_payed_yet'
},
{
    orderId: 3,
    orderDate: '2018-03-01',
    orderAmount: 100,
    payedAmount: 80
},
{
    orderId: 4,
    orderDate: '2018-03-01',
    orderAmount: 100,
    payedAmount: 'not_payed_yet'
}]
```

Anybody got any tips?

Comment: Where is the data from? If it is from a database, you could solve this with a simple join on the server side.

Comment: asking for llibrary is ot. please add the wanted result as well, beside the problem you are facing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inner join two objects javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42429023/inner-join-two-objects-javascript)

Answer (score 6):

```
const newOrderList = orders.map((order, index) => {
   let payedOrder = ordersPayed.find(o => o.orderId === order.orderId);
   return Object.assign({}, order, payedOrder)
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try following solution:

```
// Returns an array with order objects, which contain all information
let newOrderList = orders.map((order, index) => {
    let payedOrder = ordersPayed.find(o => o.orderId === order.orderId);

    // Returns a new object to not manipulate the original one
    return {
        orderId: order.orderId,
        orderDate: order.orderDate, 
        orderAmount: order.orderAmount, 
        payedAmount: payedOrder ? payedOrder.payedAmount : 'not_payed_yet', 
        debitorName: payedOrder ? payedOrder.debitorName: 'not_known_yet'
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [lodash](https://lodash.com/) and ES6 arrow notation the solution can become quite short:

```js
// Array of Javascript Objects 1:
const orders = [{
    orderId: 1,
    orderDate: '2018-01-01',
    orderAmount: 100
  },
  {
    orderId: 2,
    orderDate: '2018-02-01',
    orderAmount: 100
  },
  {
    orderId: 3,
    orderDate: '2018-03-01',
    orderAmount: 100
  },
  {
    orderId: 4,
    orderDate: '2018-03-01',
    orderAmount: 100
  }
];

// Array of Javascript Objects 2:
const ordersPayed = [{
    orderId: 1,
    payedAmount: 90,
    debitorName: 'abc'
  },
  {
    orderId: 3,
    payedAmount: 80,
    debitorName: 'abc'
  },
  {
    orderId: 6,
    payedAmount: 90,
    debitorName: 'abc'
  }
];


var merged = _.merge(_.keyBy(orders, 'orderId'), _.keyBy(ordersPayed, 'orderId'));

const newArr = _.map(merged, o => _.assign({
  "payedAmount": "not_payed_yet",
  "debitorName": "not_known_yet"
}, o));

var result = _.values(newArr);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

For your problem, I would use the `Array.reduce` with `Array.find`:

```
const newOrderList = orders.reduce((acc, order) => {
    const { orderId } = order;
    const orderPayed =  ordersPayed.find((orderPayed) => orderPayed.orderId === orderId);

    if (orderPayed) {
        return [
            ...acc,
            {
                ...order,
                ...orderPayed,
            }
        ];
    }

    return [
        ...acc,
        {
            ...order,
        },
    ];
}, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a small error in you code. The `else if` there is not going to work the way you want, because you will always push a `not found` entry to the new array, whenever the last match fails. You could try this adjusted version of your code:

```js
const orders = [
{
    orderId: 1,
    orderDate: '2018-01-01',
    orderAmount: 100
},
{
    orderId: 2,
    orderDate: '2018-02-01',
    orderAmount: 100
},
{
    orderId: 3,
    orderDate: '2018-03-01',
    orderAmount: 100
},
{
    orderId: 4,
    orderDate: '2018-03-01',
    orderAmount: 100
}];
    
const ordersPayed = [
{
    orderId: 1,
    payedAmount: 90,
    debitorName: 'abc'
},
{
    orderId: 3,
    payedAmount: 80,
    debitorName: 'abc'
},
{
    orderId: 6,
    payedAmount: 90,
    debitorName: 'abc'
}];

let newOrderList = [];
    
for (i = 0; i < orders.length; i++) {
    let payed = false;
    for (j = 0; j < ordersPayed.length; j++) {
        if (orders[i].orderId == ordersPayed[j].orderId) {
            newOrderList.push({ orderId: orders[i].orderId,
                                orderDate: orders[i].orderDate,
                                orderAmount: orders[i].orderAmount,
                                payedAmount: ordersPayed[j].payedAmount,
                                debitorName: ordersPayed[j].debitorName });
            payed = true;
        }
    }
    if (!payed) {
        newOrderList.push({ orderId: orders[i].orderId,
                            orderDate: orders[i].orderDate,
                            orderAmount: orders[i].orderAmount,
                            payedAmount: 'not_payed_yet',
                            debitorName: 'not_known_yet' });
    }
}
    
console.log(newOrderList);
```

But keep in mind that this is only going to work if you have a `1:1` relationship between the datasets. Meaning if you can have multiple entries in `ordersPayed` for an entry in `orders`, the result is also going to have multiple entries for those orders.