# Json array creation using javascript / jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

User Details

```
 var UserDetails=[{"UserId":1,"Name":"Vineeth"},{"UserId":2,"Name":"Sreena"}]
```

Call Details

```
var CallSummary=[{"UserId":1,"UPerCalls":"22 %","UTotalCallTime":"60:24 minutes","UPerCallsTime":"0 %","UAvgCallTime":"0:22 minutes"},{"UserId":2,"UPerCalls":"8 %","UTotalCallTime":"50373:16 minutes","UPerCallsTime":"50 %","UAvgCallTime":"839:33 minutes"}]
```

Expected Result

```
var Result=[{"UserId":1,"Name":"Vineeth","UPerCalls":"22 %","UTotalCallTime":"60:24 minutes","UPerCallsTime":"0 %","UAvgCallTime":"0:22 minutes"},{"UserId":2,"Name":"Sreena","UPerCalls":"8 %","UTotalCallTime":"50373:16 minutes","UPerCallsTime":"50 %","UAvgCallTime":"839:33 minutes"}]
```

How to get this result, my code is ,

```js
var UserDetails=[{"UserId":1,"Name":"Vineeth"},{"UserId":2,"Name":"Sreena"}]

var CallSummary=[{"UserId":1,"UPerCalls":"22 %","UTotalCallTime":"60:24 minutes","UPerCallsTime":"0 %","UAvgCallTime":"0:22 minutes"},{"UserId":2,"UPerCalls":"8 %","UTotalCallTime":"50373:16 minutes","UPerCallsTime":"50 %","UAvgCallTime":"839:33 minutes"}]


var UserSummary = [];
$.each(UserDetails, function(key, index) {
    $.each(CallSummary, function(key, index1) {
        if (index.UserId == index1.UserId) {
            UserSummary.push({
                UserId: index.UserId
            });
            UserSummary.push({
                Name: index.Name
            });
            UserSummary.push({
                TotalPerCalls: index1.UPerCalls
            });
            UserSummary.push({
                TotalCallTime: index1.UTotalCallTime
            });
            UserSummary.push({
                TotalPerCallTime: index1.UPerCallsTime
            });
            UserSummary.push({
                TotalAvgCallTime: index1.UAvgCallTime
            });
        }
    })
})

console.log(UserSummary);
```

How to solve this ???

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JS - Merge two array of objects based on a key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46849286/js-merge-two-array-of-objects-based-on-a-key)

Comment: And may be this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42429023/how-can-i-perform-an-inner-join-with-two-object-arrays-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do follow the steps like:

1. Loop the `UserDetails` array to get each object in that array
2. Then find the object in `CallSummary` array with matching `UserId` value
3. Merge the object if the `UserId` is same using `Object.assign()`
4. Push the new object in the array `UserSummary`

```js
var UserDetails=[{"UserId":1,"Name":"Vineeth"},{"UserId":2,"Name":"Sreena"}];

var CallSummary=[{"UserId":1,"UPerCalls":"22 %","UTotalCallTime":"60:24 minutes","UPerCallsTime":"0 %","UAvgCallTime":"0:22 minutes"},{"UserId":2,"UPerCalls":"8 %","UTotalCallTime":"50373:16 minutes","UPerCallsTime":"50 %","UAvgCallTime":"839:33 minutes"}];

var UserSummary = [];
UserDetails.forEach((userDetail) => {
  var callSummary = CallSummary.find(({UserId})=> UserId === userDetail.UserId);
  var newObj = Object.assign(userDetail, callSummary);
  UserSummary.push(newObj);
});
console.log(UserSummary);
```

Comment: How to find a specific user data from this second array

Comment: It is there. You need to use `find()`

Comment: I have only second array and a value, no two arrays

Answer (score 3):

You only need an iteration. By doing [.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) you loop through the Users and for each user, create a new object in the UserSummary array. Then inside that object you '[spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)' the properties of both the UserDetails object corresponding to that user and the properties of CallSummary.

```js
var UserDetails=[{"UserId":1,"Name":"Vineeth"},{"UserId":2,"Name":"Sreena"}];
var CallSummary=[{"UserId":1,"UPerCalls":"22 %","UTotalCallTime":"60:24 minutes","UPerCallsTime":"0 %","UAvgCallTime":"0:22 minutes"},{"UserId":2,"UPerCalls":"8 %","UTotalCallTime":"50373:16 minutes","UPerCallsTime":"50 %","UAvgCallTime":"839:33 minutes"}];

var UserSummary=UserDetails.map((user, index) => ({...user, ...CallSummary[index]}));

console.log(UserSummary);
```

Comment: can you please show the full code. I see only .......  var UserSummary=UserDetails.map((user, index) => ({...user, ...CallSummary[index]}));

Answer (score 1):

Just use `Object.assign({}, index, index1)` which return combined result of `index` and `index1`.

```js
var UserDetails=[{"UserId":1,"Name":"Vineeth"},{"UserId":2,"Name":"Sreena"}]

var CallSummary=[{"UserId":1,"UPerCalls":"22 %","UTotalCallTime":"60:24 minutes","UPerCallsTime":"0 %","UAvgCallTime":"0:22 minutes"},{"UserId":2,"UPerCalls":"8 %","UTotalCallTime":"50373:16 minutes","UPerCallsTime":"50 %","UAvgCallTime":"839:33 minutes"}]

var UserSummary = [];
$.each(UserDetails, function(key, index) {
    $.each(CallSummary, function(key, index1) {
        if (index.UserId == index1.UserId) {
            UserSummary.push(Object.assign({}, index, index1));
        }
    })
})
console.log(UserSummary);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use native functions like `.concat()`, `.reduce()` and `Object.assign()` to get this:

```js
var UserDetails = [{"UserId":1,"Name":"Vineeth"},{"UserId":2,"Name":"Sreena"}];
var CallSummary = [{"UserId":1,"UPerCalls":"22 %","UTotalCallTime":"60:24 minutes","UPerCallsTime":"0 %","UAvgCallTime":"0:22 minutes"},{"UserId":2,"UPerCalls":"8 %","UTotalCallTime":"50373:16 minutes","UPerCallsTime":"50 %","UAvgCallTime":"839:33 minutes"}];

var result = Object.values(
               UserDetails
                .concat(CallSummary)
                .reduce((r, c) => (r[c["UserId"]] = Object.assign({}, r[c["UserId"]], c), r), [])
             );
                        
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

**References:**

- [`Array.prototype.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)
- [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)
- [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)
- [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: UserDetails.concat(...).reduce is not a function

Comment: @JIJOMONK.A Can you create some fiddle of your code?

Comment: sorry bro its a mistake, can you please edit the answer. I will change it

Answer (score 1):

**Please try the below code :)
You need to assign the values to a temporary object and then push the object into the array.**

```
var UserDetails=[{"UserId":1,"Name":"Vineeth"},{"UserId":2,"Name":"Sreena"}];
var CallSummary=[{"UserId":1,"UPerCalls":"22 %","UTotalCallTime":"60:24 minutes","UPerCallsTime":"0 %","UAvgCallTime":"0:22 minutes"},{"UserId":2,"UPerCalls":"8 %","UTotalCallTime":"50373:16 minutes","UPerCallsTime":"50 %","UAvgCallTime":"839:33 minutes"}];

UserSummary=[];
        $.each(UserDetails, function(key, index) {
            $.each(CallSummary, function(key, index1) {
                if(index.UserId==index1.UserId){
                    var tempObject = {};
                    tempObject['UserId'] = index.UserId;
                    tempObject['Name'] = index.Name;
                    tempObject['TotalCalls'] = index1.TotalCalls;
                    tempObject['TotalPerCalls'] = index1.UPerCalls;
                    tempObject['TotalCallTime'] = index1.UTotalCallTime;
                    tempObject['TotalPerCallTime'] = index1.UPerCallsTime;
                    tempObject['TotalAvgCallTime'] = index1.UAvgCallTime;
                    UserSummary.push(tempObject);
                }
            })
       })

 console.log(UserSummary);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's Pretty simple: please write the logic as below

```
var UserDetails=[{"UserId":1,"Name":"Vineeth"},{"UserId":2,"Name":"Sreena"}];
var CallSummary=[{"UserId":1,"UPerCalls":"22 %","UTotalCallTime":"60:24 minutes","UPerCallsTime":"0 %","UAvgCallTime":"0:22 minutes"},{"UserId":2,"UPerCalls":"8 %","UTotalCallTime":"50373:16 minutes","UPerCallsTime":"50 %","UAvgCallTime":"839:33 minutes"}]
var array3 = CallSummary.filter(function(obj) { return UserDetails.indexOf(obj.UserId) == -1; });

console.log(array3);
```

Please see in [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: Not Same as Expected Result :)

Comment: `console.log()` must be lowerCase:)

Comment: It works fine please check the link and paste given code. then click on run. also compare your expected result