# Join two object arrays and display remaining values in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object

```
var obj = [{
    "position": "Bottom Left",
    text: "2"
}, {
    "position": "Top Center",
    image: logo,
    width: 22
}, {
    "position": "Bottom Right",
    text: "1"
}, {
    "position": "Top Left",
    text: "9"
}];
```

I'm trying to join using `position` key with two other object arrays(`pdf_header` and `pdf_footer`) and save the remaining object key values in `pdf_header_output` and `pdf_footer_output` respectively. If the value is not present in `obj`, then an empty object should push.

```
var pdf_header = [{
    "position": "Top Left"
}, {
    "position": "Top Center"
}, {
    "position": "Top Right"
}];
var pdf_footer = [{
    "position": "Bottom Left"
}, {
    "position": "Bottom Center"
}, {
    "position": "Bottom Right"
}];
```

**Expected Output:**

```
var pdf_header_output = [{
    text: "9"
}, {
    image: logo,
    width: 22
}, {}];
var pdf_footer_output = [{
    text: "2"
}, {}, {
    text: "1"
}];
```

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42429023/how-can-i-perform-an-inner-join-with-two-object-arrays-in-javascript), but didn't work as expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to map over each item in `pdf_header` or `pdf_footer` and find the matching element in `obj`. Then extract all properties except the `position` one.

```js
var obj = [{ "position": "Bottom Left", text: "2" }, { "position": "Top Center", image: 'logo', width: 22 }, { "position": "Bottom Right", text: "1" }, { "position": "Top Left", text: "9" }];

var pdf_header = [{ "position": "Top Left" }, { "position": "Top Center" }, { "position": "Top Right" }];
var pdf_footer = [{ "position": "Bottom Left" }, { "position": "Bottom Center" }, { "position": "Bottom Right" }];


function findByPosition(object, positions) {
  return positions.map(({
    position
  }) => {
    const item = object.find(({
      position: objPosition
    }) => objPosition === position);
    if (item) {
      const {
        position: throwaway,
        ...rest
      } = item;
      return rest;
    }
    return {};
  });
}

var pdf_header_output = findByPosition(obj, pdf_header);
var pdf_footer_output = findByPosition(obj, pdf_footer);

console.log(pdf_header_output);
console.log(pdf_footer_output);
```

```html
I'm var pdf_header_output = [{ text: "9" }, { image: logo, width: 22 }, {}]; var pdf_footer_output = [{ text: "2" }, {}, { text: "1" }];
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you please explain the code?

Answer (score 1):

```js
let obj = [
  { 'position': 'Bottom Left', text: '2' },
  { 'position': 'Top Center', image: 'logo', width: 22 },
  { 'position': 'Bottom Right', text: '1' },
  { 'position': 'Top Left', text: '9' }
]

let pdf_header = [
  { 'position': 'Top Left' },
  { 'position': 'Top Center' },
  { 'position': 'Top Right' }
]

let pdf_footer = [
  { 'position': 'Bottom Left' },
  { 'position': 'Bottom Center' },
  { 'position': 'Bottom Right' }
]

let pdf_header_output = pdf_header.map(header => {
    const items = obj.filter(item => item.position === header.position)[0]
    return items !== undefined && 'position' in items ? ( ({ position, ...o }) => o )(items) : {}
  }
)

console.log(pdf_header_output)

let pdf_footer_output = pdf_footer.map(header => {
      const items = obj.filter(item => item.position === header.position)[0]
      return items !== undefined && 'position' in items ? ( ({ position, ...o }) => o )(items) : {}
    }
)

console.log(pdf_footer_output)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use modern JS here is my solution:

```js
var obj = [{ "position": "Bottom Left", text: "2" }, { "position": "Top Center", image: 'logo', width: 22 }, { "position": "Bottom Right", text: "1" }, { "position": "Top Left", text: "9" }];

var pdf_header = [{ "position": "Top Left" }, { "position": "Top Center" }, { "position": "Top Right" }];
var pdf_footer = [{ "position": "Bottom Left" }, { "position": "Bottom Center" }, { "position": "Bottom Right" }];

var pdf_header_output = getPropsFrom(pdf_header);
var pdf_footer_output = getPropsFrom(pdf_footer);

function getPropsFrom(array) {
  var props = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    props.push(getPropByPosition(array[i]));
  }
  return props;
}

function getPropByPosition(element) {
  for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    if (obj[i].position === element.position) {
      return getCopyWithoutPosition(obj[i]);
    }
  }
  return {};
}

function getCopyWithoutPosition(o) {
  var copy = Object.assign({}, o);
  delete copy.position;
  return copy;
}

console.log(pdf_header_output);
console.log(pdf_footer_output);
```