# Merging two arrays on id - map function - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to merge two arrays on an id (sourceID). But fail to do so. The first array is the one below:

```
eventsToBeInserted = [{sourceID: 1, name: "BettyNansen"}, {sourceID: 2, name: "kongenshave"}]
```

This is the second array:

```
images = [{sourceID: 1, images: "Bettynansen.jpg"}, {sourceID: 2, name: "kongenshave.jpg"}]
```

I am looking to get the following:

```
events = [{sourceID: 1, name: "BettyNansen", images: "Bettynansen.jpg"}, {sourceID: 2, name: "kongenshave", images: "kongenshave.jpg"}]
```

This is my code:

```js
const eventsToBeInserted = [{
  sourceID: 1,
  name: "BettyNansen"
}, {
  sourceID: 2,
  name: "kongenshave"
}]

const images = [{
  sourceID: 1,
  images: "Bettynansen.jpg"
}, {
  sourceID: 2,
  name: "kongenshave.jpg"
}]

events: !!eventsToBeInserted ? eventsToBeInserted.sourceID.map(sourceID => {
  const event = images.name.find(eventLookup => eventLookup.sourceID === sourceID);
  return [eventsToBeInserted.name, images.name]
}) : []
```

Comment: Link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35903850/combine-json-arrays-by-key-javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically what you want is, for every element in `eventsToBeInserted`, find all images that belong to it in the `images` array.

**Note**: In your `images` array, the first element has a property `images` and the second one has a property `name`.

```
const images = [{
  sourceID: 1,
  images: "Bettynansen.jpg"
// ^
}, {
  sourceID: 2,
  name: "kongenshave.jpg"
// ^
}]
```

It seems logical that both should use `name` so that's what my examples bellow will assume. If those objects can use both `images` and `name`, then you should `||` the two properties in the preferred order of existence when retrieving the value.

```js
const eventsToBeInserted=[{sourceID:1,name:"BettyNansen"},{sourceID:2,name:"kongenshave"}],images=[{sourceID:1,name:"Bettynansen.jpg"},{sourceID:2,name:"kongenshave.jpg"}];

console.log(
  eventsToBeInserted.map(
    event => Object.assign({}, event, {
      images: images
        .filter(img => img.sourceID === event.sourceID)
        .map(img => img.name)
    })
  )
)
```

If each object will always match to only 1 image, as per your example, you can use `find` instead of `filter` on the `images` array:

**Note**: If you'll only ever have one image, it would make more sense to name that property `image` instead of `images`.

```js
const eventsToBeInserted=[{sourceID:1,name:"BettyNansen"},{sourceID:2,name:"kongenshave"}],images=[{sourceID:1,name:"Bettynansen.jpg"},{sourceID:2,name:"kongenshave.jpg"}];

console.log(
  eventsToBeInserted.map(
    event => Object.assign({}, event, {
      image: (
        images.find(img => img.sourceID === event.sourceID) || {}
      ).name
    })
  )
)
```

If this operation needs to happen many times, converting `images` to a hash of `sourceID: imageName` would be more efficient.

```js
const eventsToBeInserted=[{sourceID:1,name:"BettyNansen"},{sourceID:2,name:"kongenshave"}],images=[{sourceID:1,name:"Bettynansen.jpg"},{sourceID:2,name:"kongenshave.jpg"}];

const imagesHash = images.reduce((hash, img) => {
  hash[img.sourceID] = img.name;
  return hash;
}, {});

console.log(
  eventsToBeInserted.map(
    event => Object.assign({}, event, {
      image: imagesHash[event.sourceID]
    })
  )
)
```

Finally, assuming your environment allows it, you could use [object spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator#Spread_in_object_literals) to simplify the syntax:

```js
const eventsToBeInserted=[{sourceID:1,name:"BettyNansen"},{sourceID:2,name:"kongenshave"}],images=[{sourceID:1,name:"Bettynansen.jpg"},{sourceID:2,name:"kongenshave.jpg"}];

const imagesHash = images.reduce((hash, img) => {
  hash[img.sourceID] = img.name;
  return hash;
}, {});

console.log(
  eventsToBeInserted.map(
    event => ({
      ...event,
      image: imagesHash[event.sourceID]
    })
  )
)
```

Comment: Thank you @nem035. Really appreciate the thorough and detailed explanation!

Comment: @BjarkeAndersen no problem, glad to help amigo :)